# Swift: Accessibility: How can I queue events to be executed in sequence?

Tags: swift, accessibility

I want to know if there is a way to queue up accessibility readouts or element focus events one after another.

If I use either: UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, "My Error Message")

or:
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, self.continueButton)

The second call will interrupt the readout that is currently being read.

And obviously, if you use Dispatch with Delay, it's not robust, because different languages have different lengths of content, and also the user has a different readout speed set, which may be set to very slow.  So how can I "queue up" multiple focus/read out events and ensure that only one of them gets read out at a time in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you post your first announcement you need to wait for `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification` (see more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/notification_names?language=objc)) before you post the 2nd one.

So build a queue (a set could do it) and whenever `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification` is triggered by the system just pop the first notification in your set (if present) and fire it away.